# Move SCNNode forward when long pressing

Tags: swift, touch, nodes, scenekit, move

Ive been trying to move a cube forward when the user long presses the screen. I can't get it to move smoothly. Is there any way I can move it only forward (in the negative direction) and update the position on each frame the scene?

Here is what I have so far:

```
var carLocation = SCNVector3(x:0, y: 0, z:-0.01) 

func setupScene() {
        sceneView = self.view as? SCNView
        scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Map.scn")
        sceneView.scene = scene
        let holdRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
        holdRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameViewController.hold(recognizer:)))
        sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(holdRecognizer)
    }

 @objc func hold(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Held down!")
        let position = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
        carLocation = SCNVector3(x:0, y: 0, z:-0.01)
        carNode.physicsBody?.velocity += carLocation
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible it's "jumpy" because you are waiting for a LongPress each time?  Or is it supposed to follow a drag once a long press has been initiated?

Comment: @Voltan The cube appears jumpy when it moves. Since the velocity is being added in a specific direction it does not need to follow the drag.

Comment: I did a quick test and I have it going forward and backward smoothly.  Too much to post in comments, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I put a count in your print, just so you could see that LongPress is going to repeat itself...  'a lot', which is probably not what you want long term.  So, assuming you created something like:

```
let p = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
p.isAffectedByGravity = false
shipNode.physicsBody = p
```

Then this will move your object forward and backward smoothly.

```
@objc func hold(recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Held down! \(count)")
    count += 1
    shipNode.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0, 0.51) 
}
@objc func handleTap(_ gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    shipNode.physicsBody?.velocity = SCNVector3Make(0.0, 0, -0.51)
}
```

Unless you have a ton of objects in there, I can't see any reason for it to be slow.  Set scnView.showsStatistics = true to see your FPS. Hopefully, you are not trying to run scenekit in the simulator?